# Unable to connect to postgres, redis from nodejs server in docker container: getting connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, redis

-- Docker FIle

```
FROM node:4.4.2
EXPOSE 3000
ENV NODE_ENV test
WORKDIR /app
COPY ["package.json", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install --silent
COPY . /app
CMD node server.js
```

-- DOCKER-COMPOSE

```
version: "2"
services:
postgresql:
    image: postgres:9.5.21
    container_name: postgresql
    volumes:
        - '$HOME/DOCKER_VOLUME/db-data1:$HOME/DOCKER_VOLUME/var/lib/postgres'
    environment:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: <PWD>
        POSTGRES_DB: <DB>
        POSTGRES_USER: <UERS>
    ports:
        - '5432:5432'
redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    ports:
        - '6379:6379'
broker:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    container_name: mosquitto
    volumes:
        - $HOME/DOCKER_VOLUME/etc/mosquitto:$HOME/DOCKER_VOLUME/etc/mosquitto:ro
        - $HOME/DOCKER_VOLUME/var/log/mosquitto:$HOME/DOCKER_VOLUME/var/log/mosquitto:rw
    ports:
        - '1883:1883'
app:
    container_name: ms_user_manager
    environment:
        NODE_ENV: test
    build: .
    volumes:
        - .:/app
        - /app/node_modules
    depends_on:
        - postgresql
        - redis
        - broker
    ports:
        - '3000:3000'
```

I am able to access postgres, redis outside of container but nodejs app unable to connect to both & giving error

```
Redis - connection to 0.0.0.0:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:6379"

Postgres - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:5432
```

So  any idea, what I am doing wrong or what i missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Node.js app should try to connect to `redis:6379`. Change this in your application configuration. At the moment it looks like it is trying to connect to localhost (which works probably when you run your server locally on the host).